# How to start a parallel process in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 python scripts. Is it possible to somehow run the second script from the first in parallel?

How to return a value from the second script to the first?

For example:

```
#script 1

def train():
  .......
return True
```

and

```
#script 2 

t = threading.Thread(target=train.train)
t.start()
```

You must close the process when the function returns true. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Python script parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518282/running-python-script-parallel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do parallel programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve -- can you elaborate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run separate processes in parallel - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080792/run-separate-processes-in-parallel-python)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to somehow run the second script from the first in parallel?

Yes we can using multiprocessing module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)).

> How to return a value from the second script to the first?

In that this section explains far enough [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)  to deal with above query

> You must close the process when the function returns true

Same Section  [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)  to deal with above query

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And to get the return values, use a `Queue` (which was designed with threads in mind; it is thread-safe).

```
# script 1
def train(queue, x):
    queue.put(x)

# script 2
import threading
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=train.train, args=(q, 1))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=train.train, args=(q, 2))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

while not q.empty():
    print(q.get())
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```

Comment: I do not want to wait for the end of the second process. I want to run this in parallel. Therefore I can not use .join ()

Comment: Do you mean you want the threads to run in parallel with each other? Or do they have to run in parallel with something else (e.g. the main thread)?

Comment: @Алевтина Did you try running this without `.join()`?

Comment: yes. In this case, everything works. But I want to run the function every time as soon as my condition is fulfilled, get the True result from it as a confirmation of completion.

This is a problem because I cannot use .start () a second time because the process is not completed.